# Laptop booting only while plugged and keyboard doesn't work either after HDD replacement

Tags: laptop, keyboard, power, laptop-repair, replacement

Recently I had problems with a laptop (tried to solve them in a [previous thread](https://superuser.com/q/1639192/167207)). I managed to remove HDD and replace it with another one from another old laptop.

While trying to put in the last screw of the back of the laptop, I noticed that the newly mounted HDD was probably a millimeter or 2 higher than the original one.

I thought that while it may be impractical to have a little bump at the back, but I needed to check out whether the replacement helped or not. When tried to switch on the laptop, it showed no sign of power. I thought that it took me few minutes to replace, so maybe the battery is low and I just plugged it in and powered it on. It started booting, but when I tried to type in credentials I found out that the keyboard is not working at all.

Later I found out that while during startup caps lock flashes once, but then seems dead - I think this implies, that the keyboard is plugged in correctly and is alright. Also after few tries, I can proclaim that the laptop won't start booting or anything unless plugged in outlet.

Can anybody help?

As commenters suggested checking out the ribbon cable, I append photo of it’s current state - I don’t see anything wrong right there, but feel free to correct me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/737AB.jpg

Comment: It sounds to me like the keyboard ribbon cable is dislodged/partially dislodged. Try reopening the laptop, remove and reseating it. A caps lock key flashing is not, in my eyes, evidence a keyboard is properly plugged in.

Comment: @davidgo already tried to check whether it's properly connected and everything seemed ok to me

Comment: Check keyboard ribbon cable for damage, especially at the places where it bends.

Comment: @dmmedia as ive mentioned earlier, it look okay to me, but even in the case its damaged- could it be the reason why my laptop boots up only while plugged in power?

Comment: Laptop mainboard may consist of several subboards. Check that all boards have proper connections. Might it be that the board controlling battery and keyboard was disconnected and left unnoticed?

Comment: just checked the board which supplies both battery and keyboard, checked its connection to power - nothing suspicious